# C#/WPF, how to make a window (created with Window.ShowDialog()) title bar blink when clicking its parent window (like MessageBox does)?

Tags: c#, wpf, messagebox, showdialog

I'm trying to create a custom MessageBox by using a WPF Window that is called with `ShowDialog()`.

So far, I've managed to implement everything, except for one thing.

As you know, when you use `MessageBox.Show("text");` you cannot set the focus or click the parent window (the one that called the `MessageBox`). If you do try to click the parent window, the `MessageBox` will blink briefly in order to alert you that you must close if first.

Windows created with `Window.ShowDialog();`, however, do not show that behavior. In fact, while you cannot set the focus to the parent window, the child (called with `ShowDialog()`) will never blink briefly.

My question is, is there any way to implement that in WPF? I've been searching for an answer but I must admit, I am stumped.

Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 12):

You need to set the [`Owner`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.window.owner.aspx) of the modal window correctly, e.g. using the following code from within the owning window:

```
Window win = new SomeModalWindow();
win.Owner = this;
win.ShowDialog();
```

Answer (score 3):

You would have to set `Owner` property of the child `Window` to the parent `Window`.  See the MSDN Documentation [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.window.owner.aspx).